# php self submit and record update

Tags: php, forms

I have multiple buttons on a single page. I need when I click a button that the same page reloads, but a counter and name of button clicked be updated. And as many times I do that, the list of clicked buttons and name of buttons should be maintained. Something like a visitor of site concept and counter.

e.g.

Button1 (value "Milk")
Button2 (value "Cereals")
etc...

Now pressing any of the buttons above will be like:

List:
Item1: Button 1 - value of button 
item2: .... etc

I will have then a submit button that once am done with adding the items I need to list, I click and go to review what I selected...

Any idea how this can be done via php only without JS?

Thanks, and sorry if not so clear but I tried my best

Comment: Are you wanting this data to stay there forever? Like when you leave and come back to the page its still there?

Comment: No @HarryBeasant I want it there until I submit the whole list and then process the list items as I see fit...after that it can be erased

Comment: anything specific I could start looking at? I mean a special API

Comment: jQuery would be good for this.

Comment: @HarryBeasant what about this:: I self-submit the page...and each time check a session variable...if it has a value, take it and store it to the array that is the list. then clear that session variable for next submit. when done, just process that array...possible?\

Comment: Yeah that would definitely work, i can write an example for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a form that submits to itself, in conjunction with sessions that retain the data for as long as you want it.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST)):

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION[$key] = (isset($_SESSION[$key]) ? $_SESSION[$key]+= 1 : 1);
}
endif;
?>
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method='post' action=''>
<input type='submit' name='milk' value='Milk'>
<input type='submit' name='cereals' value='Cereals'>
</form>
Milk: <?php echo $_SESSION['milk']; ?>
Cereals: <?php echo $_SESSION['cereals']; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A very quick example. Obviously you'll need another button for a final submit, which in turn will clear the session.

Answer (score 2):

```
< ?php
     if($_POST['mil'])
     {
            $_SESSION['count']++;
    ....     // milk button only
     }
 if($_POST['cre'])
     {
           $_SESSION['count']++;
    ....     // cereals button only

     } 
     if($_POST['mil'] or $_POST['cre'])
     {
            $_SESSION['count']++;
    ....   // Any (milk or cereals) button 
                cked this block executed
 }
 echo $_SESSION['count'];      // get total 
?>
<form method='post' action=''>
<input type='submit' name='mil' value='Milk'>
<input type='submit' name='cre' value='Cereals'>
</form>
```

Which submit button clicked,that block only executed. The form submitted the same page.

Comment: This wont save the data, so it wont continue to increment, depending on how many times you click it, it will only ever = 1

Answer (score 1):

using SESSIONS

```
< ?php
session_start();
     if($_POST['mil'])
     {
     $count = ($_SESSION['count'] = $count++);
        // $count would hold the incremented value for each time it is clicked
     }
 if($_POST['cre'])
     {
       $count1 = ($_SESSION['count1'] = $count1++);

     } 
     if($_POST['mil'] or $_POST['cre'])
     {
    ....   // Any (milk or cereals) button 
                cked this block executed
 }
?>
<form method='post' action=''>
<input type='submit' name='mil' value='Milk'>
<input type='submit' name='cre' value='Cereals'>
</form>
```

This is the basic idea.